# Setting up Docker container for MySQL database with Prisma

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a Docker container for a MySQL database using Prisma, and I'm encountering some issues. Here is my current Docker Compose file:
`

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '4466:4466'
    environment:
      - PRISMA_CONFIG: |
          managementApiSecret: secret-123
          port: 4466
          databases:
            default:
              connector: mysql
              host: mysql-db
              port: 3306
              user: root
              password: my_pass
              migrations: true
  mysql-db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER: root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD: my_pass
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_root_pass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE: my_database
    volumes: -mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    command:
      [
        'bash',
        '-c',
        'while ! mysqladmin ping -hmysql-db --silent; do sleep 1; done && echo "Database is up and running!"'
      ]

volumes:
  mysql: ~
```

So the problem is that when I run 'docker-compose up -d', I'm getting an error: "setenv: The parameter is incorrect." It does not matter is it cmd or powershell, the same error occurs.

I would appreciate any insights on how to correctly set up a docker container.

Comment: Two obvious problems with `mysql-db`: the `volumes:` content needs to be on a separate line and have a space after the hyphen `- mysql:...`; the `command` runs a loop waiting for MySQL to be available _instead of_ normally running the database, and you should just delete it.  The long multi-line environment variable is unusual but the Compose YAML looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue might be related to the way you are defining the PRISMA_CONFIG environment variable. The YAML syntax doesn't require a colon (:) after the key when using the | scalar style for a block scalar.

Here is an updated version of your Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '4466:4466'
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        managementApiSecret: secret-123
        port: 4466
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mysql
            host: mysql-db
            port: 3306
            user: root
            password: my_pass
            migrations: true
  mysql-db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER: root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD: my_pass
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_root_pass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE: my_database
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    command:
      [
        'bash',
        '-c',
        'while ! mysqladmin ping -hmysql-db --silent; do sleep 1; done && 
echo "Database is up and running!"'
      ]

volumes:
  mysql: ~
```

Changes made:

1. Removed the hyphen (-) after PRISMA_CONFIG:to correct the syntax.
2. Adjusted the indentation for the PRISMA_CONFIG block to ensure proper nesting.

Try using this modified version and see if it resolves the issue. After making the changes, run docker-compose up -d again. If you encounter any other issues, please provide the specific error message so that we can further assist you.